# How works the cookie authentication with Apollo client and graphQl from React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I can not see what I am goind wrong with the Apollo Server and the Apollo CLient authentication with GraphQl and React.

From The server side I have this:

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: process.env.ALLOW_ORIGINS
}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

//Express session:  It provides the functionality to save session data in a storage that you choose
app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => uuidv4(),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRECT,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, secure: false, maxAge: null }
}));

// ‍ passport init
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session());

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req, res }) => {
    const contextualized = buildContext({ req, res, User })
    return contextualized
  },
  playground: {
    settings: {
      'request.credentials': 'same-origin',
    },
  },
})
```

And is working perfectly fine with my resolvers in the playground. Everything is fine so far.

I can make request from the client and get response for both, mutations and queries. But I can not store the cookie so far in my browser. And magically it works in the Playground. **Why?**

This is an example of the login resolver:

```
 login : async (root, {email, password}, context) => {
    const { user } = await context.authenticate('graphql-local', { email, password });
    if (!user) throw new Error ('‍♂️ There was a problem with the user o the password ')
    context.login(user); //
    return { user }
  },
```

After that, all my other resolvers are wrapped with a secure function, that ask for context authentication:

```
export function secure (func, sudo = false, admin = false, patron =  false) {
    return (root, args, context) => {
        if (!context.req.user) throw new AuthenticationError('Unauthenticated')
        // sudo only
        if(sudo && rol !== 'sudo' ) throw new ForbiddenError('Protected by Super User')
        if(admin && rol !== 'admin') throw new ForbiddenError('Protected by admin')
        return func(root, args, context)
    }
}
```

And this is how I have configure the Apollo Client in the react app:

```
const Client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
          ),
        );
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }),
    new HttpLink({
      uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

The problem is in the client side, cuz the authentication works in the PlayGround, but not in the react. What Can I do?

Client: https://github.com/josuevalrob/CLE
Server: https://github.com/josuevalrob/cle_api

Cheking the response for any request :
[image: Cheking the response for any request :]

Comment: not working - how? error? checked browser request/response details (browser dev tools/network)?  process.env on client - how?

Comment: The error is simple, no cookies, and authentication error appears. But that is cuz I am forcing it in a Secure middleware.

Comment: @xadm i had include that function in the question. Can you check it up?

Comment: first - test if client gets cookie, it can be checked in dev tools/data ...2nd, test if credentials are sent in following requests in dev/tools/network/post headers - compare with playground

Comment: @xadm sure, Check, I had update the question including the cookie response. That comes from any request that I made to the graphql server. It is *not different with the login request*

Comment: cookie exists ... check graphql REQUEST headers in dev tools/network ...  'cookie' should be there ... compare headers with playground's requests

Comment: but, how do I send them? where should I get access? who is sending it? _How does it works?_

Comment: answer, what's the checking results ... no more questions  ;) ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#cookie ... it should work ... if host and port match

Comment: @xadm What do you mean? I have the Apollo Client in the comments. I am using cookies configuration recomended from apollo. Btw, They are in the same host, but not in the same port. One is in the 3000 (react) and the other on is in 8000 (express).

Comment: ... then you should use credentials 'include' and cors ... as in docs ?